# Passing a `unique symbol` into a function

Tags: typescript

I have two questions about the code below:

1. Is it possible to pass something as a `Param` besides an `enum`?
2. Is it possible to get better typing at execution of `e` that states what the param key is?

Ideally both of these issues are solved by somekind of unique symbol type. `new (class extends Symbol)('alpha')`, or someth

```
enum Params {
    alpha = 'alpha'
}

const defaultParam = <T> (param: Params) => {
    return (a: { [param]: T }): T => { 
        throw new Error('need param')
    }
}

const e = defaultParam<number>(Params.alpha)
e({ beta: 2 })
```

Here's the error

```
Argument of type '{ beta: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [param]: number; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'beta' does not exist in type '{ [param]: number; }'.
```

And with `param: string`

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for symbol!

```
const defaultParam = <G extends string, T>() => {
    return (a: Record<G, T>): T => {
        throw new Error('need param')
    }
}

const x = defaultParam<'alpha', number>()
```

Or if param is needed as variable:

```
const defaultParam = <T>() => {
    return <G extends string>(param: G) => {
        return (a: Record<G, T>): T => {
            throw new Error('Need ${param}')
        }
    }
}

const x = defaultParam<number>()('alpha')
```